# making arrays from reading file

Tags: arrays, c, file-io

I have a program in which I am reading a file with geographical coordinates and values which looks like this:

```
-90 0 0.5
-90 1 0.2
-90 2 0.12
-90 3 0.15
  ...
-89 0 0.56
-89 1 0.12
  ...
```

This file has 64800 rows.  What I want to do is make an array of the values in the first column in the text file which are latitudes, an array of values in the second column which are longitudes and finally a third array of the final column values.

Below is a snippet of the program I am using to try to accomplish this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE    *fp=NULL;
    char    inpFname[81];
    int     i,j,k;
    char    buf[8000];
    char    lat[100],lon[100],val[100];
    float   latnum,lonnum,valnum;
    float   latarray[64800],lonarray[64800],valarray[64800];

    sprintf(inpFname,"100_2021120700.txt");
    printf("%s\n",inpFname);

    if ((fp=fopen(inpFname,"rt"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nERROR: Cannot open/read input file [%s]\n\n",inpFname);
        exit(1);
    } 

    i=0;
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        fgets(buf,8000,fp);
        sscanf(buf,"%s %s %s\n",lat,lon,val);
        latnum=atof(lat);
        lonnum=atof(lon);
        valnum=atof(val);

        printf("%d) lat %0.3f lon %0.3f value %0.3f\n",i,latnum,lonnum,valnum);     
        latarray[i]=latnum;
        lonarray[i]=lonnum;
        valarray[i]=valnum;
    
        i=i+1;  
    }

}
```

Unfortunately I am getting a segmentation fault when running this program.  If I take out one array then it runs fine.  How do I tweak this program so I can make arrays out of each of the three columns of the text file?

Comment: Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) Who is teaching this? Note it's unwise to have such large stack data as `float latarray[64800], lonarray[64800], valarray[64800];`.

Comment: You have three very big arrays allocated on the stack. Consider allocating those arrays dynamically: `float* latarray = malloc(sizeof(float) * 64800);` &c. (Use `free(latarray)` when you're done.)

Comment: The program lacks error checking – the success of `fgets` and of `sscanf`, or the array index.

Comment: Instead of 3 arrays, it's usually better design to have an array of structures.

Comment: Instead of scanning into strings and then calling `atof()`, why don't you just use `%f` format in the `scanf()` string?

Comment: How do I define the arrays?  I get error message with float* latarray = malloc(sizeof(float * 64800)     fileread.c: In function ‘int main(int, char*)’: fileread.c:16:51: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘float*’ [-fpermissive] float* latarray = ...

Answer (score 0):

**No iteration limit**

Avoid iterating too much.  With `while(!feof(fp))` code [likely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) iterates 1 too many.

```
// while(!feof(fp))
//{
//    fgets(buf,8000,fp);

while (i < 64800 && fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
```

**Large local object**

Consider allocating

```
// float   latarray[64800],lonarray[64800],valarray[64800];
#define N 64800
float *latarray = malloc(sizeof *latarray * N);
float *lonarray = malloc(sizeof *lonarray * N);
float *valarray = malloc(sizeof *valarray * N);
```

Robust code would also check for allocation success.

```
if (latarray == NULL || ...) Handle_OutOfMemory();
```

**Unsafe scan**

`sscanf(buf,"%s %s %s\n",lat,lon,val);` may overflow buffers.  Use `sscanf(buf,"%99s %99s %99s",lat,lon,val);` or

```
if (sscanf(buf,"%f %f %f", &latnum, &lonnum, &valnum) != 3) {
  Handle_ParsingError();
}
```

Or look to `strtof()`.

**Missing `fclose()`**

Clean-up when done.

Comment: I tried this and got the following errors for the float *array = malloc code:   fileread.c: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
fileread.c:16:51: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘float*’ [-fpermissive]
  float*  latarray = malloc(sizeof(float) * 64800);
                                                   ^

Comment: @jms1980 Are you using a C compiler? or some other language compiler like C++ for this C question?  BTW this answer does not use `sizeof(float)`.